# C++20 std::source_location yield different column numbers between free function and template functions

Tags: c++, c++20, function-templates, std-source-location

Consider the template function `g()` and free function `f()`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <source_location>

auto g(auto...) {
std::cout << std::source_location::current().column() << "\n";
}

auto f() {
std::cout << std::source_location::current().column() << "\n";
}

int main() {
g();
f();
}
```

Compiled with [GCC-trunk](https://godbolt.org/z/eYf6GT) get following output:

```
43
44
```

Why `g()` and `f()` yield different results? I expect the results are the same. Why a unit offset disappeared during the instantiation of the template?

Comment: I would say bug, especially as feature is only in trunk so young...

Comment: If I had to guess, I would say this is likely a compiler bug. Handling column location is new to standard-C++; previous versions only had a `__LINE__` and not an equivalent `__COLUMN__`. Because of this, I wouldn't be surprised if some compilers like `gcc` suffer growing pains as they have to adapt their existing compiler code to now do proper detection.

Comment: Ok I will report this, thanks.

Comment: @康桓瑋 If you report it, please consider posting the report as an answer for visibility! I'm sure other people will encounter this eventually as well. Plus I wouldn't mind seeing their follow-up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I file a [PR 99672](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=99672) to GCC Bugzilla. Jakub Jelinek (one of the GCC contributor) reply me:

> I think the standard doesn't specify anything about what exactly the
> column should be, so using different columns isn't standard violation.

but he still did a patch to fix it.